# 'SqlException was unhandled' error when trying to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I have a program that takes information passed to it, and puts the information in a database. The program is being created in VS2008 for a Windows Ce 6.0 device, and I am having trouble connecting to the database. I want to connect over the local network, but not entirely too sure how to do so. Here is my code for the function that calls the database.

```
public void callSQL(string partNumber, int total, int numOfPacks, string dunsNumber, string serialNumber, string laneNumber)
{
    //establish connection
    string conString = "Data Source=10.97.2.67,1433;Initial Catalog=testing.mdf;User ID=**********;Persist Security Info=false";

    using (SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();

        try
        {
            //open the server
            //Insert values passed into the method
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (Part_Number, total, number_of_packs, dunsNumber, serialNumber, truck_number) VALUES (@Part_Number,@total,@number_of_packs,@dunsNumber,@serialNumber,@truck_number)", con);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Part_Number", partNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number_of_packs", numOfPacks);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dunsNumber", dunsNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serialNumber", serialNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@truck_number", laneNumber);

            //execute the query
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
           string error = e.ToString();
           error = error.ToLower();

           if (error.Contains("duplicate") == true)
           {
              Console.WriteLine("You have already scanned this barcode.");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the code stops at con.Open(); and I get an error which says

> SqlException was unhandled

Here is the information from the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException {"SqlException"}
>   [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] {"SqlException"}
>   {Systen.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCOllection}
>   LineNumber  0
>   Message     "SqlException"
>   Number      17
>   Procedure   "ConnectionOpen(Connect())."
>   Server      "10.97.2.67,1433"
>   Source      ".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
>   StackTrace
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(String host, SqlInternalConnection connHandler, Int32 timeout)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor(SqlConnection connection, Hashtable connectionOptions)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at scan.partObject.callSQL(String partNumber, Int32 total, Int32 numOfPacks, String dunsNumber, String serialNumber, String laneNumber)
>   at scan.Program.Main(String[] args)

Thanks

Comment: initial catalog probably shouldn't have the .mdf on it.  It should just be the name of the database.  Also try setting a breakpoint in your catch block and then drilling into the errors collection to get more detail.

Comment: @BlackICE even without the .mdf I'm getting the exact same result. Also what do you mean by drilling into the errors collection?

Comment: How do you get that IP address `10.97.2.67,1433`

Comment: @RajeshDhiman ipconfig and I used the IPv4 address. I tried using the ip address that I found on the SQL server but my device wasn't able to ping to it so I resorted to the IPv4 address.

Comment: Ok try removing `,1433` from your IP address and .mdf from database name.

Comment: @RajeshDhiman I tried that but still the same error

Comment: check the sqlerrors collection.  If you can't do that, start a profiler session against the server and see if you're even connecting to it, if so you should be able to get any errors that are happening server side from the profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error due to the connection string. Here is the format the connection string should be if you want to connect to a SQL server over a network.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase; Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

myServerAddress can be found on SQL properties. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your IP Address issue. Check your IP Address and try connecting it again.

IPv4 Address should have 4 domain each between 0 to 255. For details visit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)

Your IP Address is "10.97.2.67,1433", I think remove 1433 and then try again. 
In order to use port number with your IP Address, change your IP Address as "10.97.2.67:1433". Hopefully this will solve your issue.

Comment: I'm using my IPv4 address, am I supposed to be using something else?

Also if it helps, I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2005

Comment: the ',1433' was the port number, I saw some people using it so I added it to my code. I removed it yet I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: Port number should be used with ":" not with comma.
Change your IP address as 10.97.2.67:1433